# Synonym request: make [dav] a synonym of [webdav]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I propose that [dav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dav) should be made a synonym of [webdav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdav).

I was triggered by an edit review for [dav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dav) that wanted to introduce the tag excerpt

> dav is an HTTP based protocol per RFC 2518 and RFC 4918 for
> distributed authoring. This tag should be used for questions
> concerning the protocol itself as well as the use of DAV modules in
> web servers such as Apache (mod_dav).

This would make this tag a duplicate of [webdav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdav).

Looking at the current questions on [dav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dav), they are either WebDAV related (eg subversion, connecting to WebDAV servers, etc), or DAV files (a digital video format). A quick count of the questions: 36 WebDAV, 6 DAV file, 1 unclear at first glance (but probably WebDAV).

Alternatively, [dav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dav) needs to be used for the digital video format only, and other questions concerning WebDAV should be retagged to [webdav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdav)

Comment: I don't think dav is the correct tag for webdav. I've never used dav when I meant webdav.

Comment: @rene The problem is - judging by the content of the [dav] tag - that some WebDAV things refer to it as DAV only (eg Subversion, sabre/dav and some other tools). I can also live with a retag (I mean, dav only has 43 questions).

Comment: I feel like 6 out of 43 (14%) is too high of an ambiguity for a synonym. Maybe just burninate it and create a new tag for the DAV file format that has less of a chance of being confused for WebDAV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited all questions that were on [dav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dav) and retagged WebDAV related questions to [webdav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdav), and .dav file to [dav-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dav-file), and in general cleaned up the questions and voted to close where off-topic.

Answer (score 11):

I recently submitted a tag edit on [dav] which was empty. I was not aware of the tag [webdav] when I submmitted the tag edit.

I based this on a couple of things:

- a quick look at posted question using [dav] were webdav related
- the Apache2 location directives for Subversion used the DAV keyword
- The Apache2 documentation for module mod_dav uses the mnemonic DAV https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dav.html

However the RFC2518 and its successor RFC4918 both use WebDAV in the title and fairly consistently throughout the document though there are times they use the mnemonic DAV rather than WebDAV. See section 3: Terminology for instance:

> Null Resource - A resource which responds with a 404 (Not Found) to
> any HTTP/1.1 or DAV method except for PUT, MKCOL, OPTIONS and LOCK.
> A NULL resource MUST NOT appear as a member of its parent collection.

as well as section 4.1:

> The DAV property model consists of name/value pairs.  The name of a
> property identifies the property's syntax and semantics, and provides
> an address by which to refer to its syntax and semantics.

However it does make sense to make tag [dav] to be something other than WebDAV and just add a note in the tag [dav] about the WebDAV specific tag.

Comment: I think your proposed edit is the reason I posted this :)